# Binding Visibility without XAML

Tags: c#, wpf

I am quite new to WPF, and especially to DataBinding, and it is pretty hard for me to understand, how to code it without XAML. How can I bind parents visibility (parent is scrollViewer) to its child visibility (child is grid), without XAML? Here is what I am trying to do right now:

```cs
{
//Code that creates grid
//Code that creates scrollViewer
    scrollViewer.Content = grid;
    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(scrollViewer); //adding it to the main window
//Creating binding
    Binding myBinding = new Binding("Vis");
    BooleanToVisibilityConverter c = new BooleanToVisibilityConverter();
    myBinding.Source = grid.Visibility;
    myBinding.Converter = c;
    myBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
    myBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(scrollViewer, VisibilityProperty, myBinding);
}
```

And here what is my "Vis" right now:

```cs
public Visibility Vis
{
    get
    {
        return Visibility;
    }
    set
    {
        Visibility = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(Visibility);
    }
}
```

Ofcourse, right now problem is `OnPropertyChanged`, it gives me an error, and I need to put `DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs` inside, but I do not know how to. I am not sure, am I doing this right way (maybe this can be simplified?), or maybe my method will not work at all, even after fixing this error. I need it to be without XAML, because controls are created dynamically.

Comment: The `Source` of a binding is the object that will be observed, the path specifies which of its properties will be used. `new Binding("Visibility") { Source = grid }` should do the trick (assuming that `grid` is a `Grid`).

Comment: *"How can I bind parents visibility (parent is scrollViewer) to its child visibility (child is grid), without XAML?"* You don't need to. If the parent is invisible the child **cannot** be seen. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @PieterWitvoet thanks for answer. Tried to replace `myBinding.Source = grid.Visibility;` with `myBinding.Source = new Binding("Visibility") { Source = grid }`, no success.
@ChrisF I am usually interacting with grid in code, because I am adding children to it. So, it will require to add some lines every time I want to make scrollViewer invisible (and i will need to do something like `ScrollViewer scrollViewer = (ScrollViewer)LayoutRoot.FindName("scrollViewername")` everytime.

Comment: @HeideKnight: the binding I've shown should *replace* `myBinding` instead of being used as its source.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet now all the `scrollViewers` are always invisible, vene if I set `grid` visibility to visible. Also, I have removed `myBinding.Source = grid.Visibility;` line.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet ok, now it works (also had to set `scrollViewer` visibility manually). Thanks for help!

Comment: No problem. Is there a particular reason for doing all this in code, instead of using a `ListView` or `ItemsControl`? It can be bound to a collection and an item template (which will be used to display each item) can be defined in xaml. If you bind to an observable collection then it'll automatically update the UI when you add or remove an item, too.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet well, its actually old WinForms app. Now I am just recoding that app and trying to learn WPF :) I will have closer look at `ListView` and `ItemsControl` then.

Answer (score 0):

Solution provided by PieterWitvoet worked for me. I had to set `scrollViewer` visibility to `Visibility.Visible` on its creation, but everything else works just fine.